# Numerical contour integrations in the complex plane - contour deformation gives different answer for analytic kernel

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, numerical-integration, complex, special-functions

I am trying to do a contour integration in *Mathematica* numerically. In particular, I'm checking the identity:

$$ H_m^{(1)}(z) =\frac{i^{-m}}{\pi}\int_{-\pi/2 + i \infty}^{\pi/2 - i \infty} \exp[i m \beta + i z \cos\beta]\mathrm d\beta $$

In Stratton's *Electromagnetic Theory* (I am a physicist), he claims ([p. 368](http://books.google.com/books?hl=en&id=zFeWdS2luE4C&pg=PA368)) that you can freely deform the contour since the kernel is an analytic function, assuming the contour stays within a certain region. Here's a diagram (from [here](http://www.math.osu.edu/~gerlach.1/math/BVtypset/img3068.png)):

[image: admissible region for Hankel function contour]

This is all fine, and I have no problem with this; however, when I try to evaluate the contour integration in *Mathematica* with code that looks like:

```
Hmz[m_, z_] := Exp[-I m Pi/2]/Pi NIntegrate[Exp[I m B + I z Cos[B]],
                 {B, -Pi/2 + I Infinity, -Pi/2 + I Pi/2, Pi/2 - I Pi/2, Pi/2 - I Infinity}]
```

or alternatively (along a different, but apparently valid, contour):

```
Hmzother[m_, z_] :=  Exp[-I m Pi/2]/Pi NIntegrate[Exp[I m B + I z Cos[B]],
                                  {B,  -Pi/2 + I Infinity, -Pi/2, Pi/2, Pi/2 - I Infinity}]
```

I get different answers - at least for the imaginary part (particularly for small $z$). For example, evaluating for $m = 3$ and $z = 1$ gives (not actual lines of code):

```
Hmz[3, 1] == 0.0195634 - 2.72402 I
Hmzother[3, 1] == 0.0195634 - 0.248805 I
```

For reference, the true value should be `HankelH1[3,1] == 0.0195634 - 5.82152 I`. The only difference between the definition of `Hmz` and `Hmzother` here are the contours, yet they should give the same answer. Ideally, I'd like to use the contour `{B, I Infinity, 0, Pi, -I Infinity}`, but this gives an even worse disagreement.

Does anybody know how to get *Mathematica* to do the contour integral correctly in the complex plane? Thanks all.

Comment: I presume you're aware that `HankelH1[]` is built-in?

Comment: I am indeed. This integral is a merely a stepping stone to an angular spectrum representation of cylindrical functions, as well as a test case to check I am doing things the right way.

Comment: @Matthew The imaginary part of your integral strongly depends on `PrecisionGoal` and `WorkingPrecision`. You can play with them a bit. On the other hand you can get the both integrals the same assuming an appropriate `Method`, e.g. adding this option to your definitions `Method -> "NewtonCotesRule"` provides the same correct values.

Comment: @Artes         Thanks. Changing the method does help get the contours listed in my initial post to agree. This is helpful. However, if I try to go to my desired contour `{B, I Infinity, 0, Pi, -I Infinity}`, things get crazy again. The exponent in the kernel becomes very large along the contour `{Pi, -I Infinity}`. Is this a different numerical accuracy issue?

Comment: Personally, I prefer using [double-exponential quadrature](http://dx.doi.org/10.2977%2Fprims%2F1195192451) for situations like these. Here's an example, showing the use of a different contour: `myHankelH1[m_?NumericQ, z_?NumericQ] := 
 Exp[-I m Pi/2] NIntegrate[Exp[I m (ArcTan[u] - I u) + I z Cos[ArcTan[u] - I u]] (1/(1 + u^2) - I), {u, -5, 5}, Method -> "DoubleExponential"]/Pi`. The result from `myHankelH1[]` compares favorably to the built-in function. (As a matter of fact, using `Method -> "DoubleExponential"` on your two functions seems to work nicely.)

Comment: @0x4A4D        I agree that works fine for evaluation of the integral. Two points however: a) it takes much longer than `"NewtonCotesRule"`, which is no great surprise, but an important fact and b) in my case, it becomes a little harder to interpret the meaning of `u` in a physical sense in this case.

Comment: As I said, double-exponential quadrature works nicely even with your two example contours. If you're looking out for speed, then `"GaussKronrodRule"` and `"ClenshawCurtisRule"` work faster than `"NewtonCotesRule"`.

Comment: @0x4A4D It works fine with the contours  `{B, -Pi/2 + I Infinity, -Pi/2 + I Pi/2, Pi/2 - I Pi/2, Pi/2 - I Infinity} `and `{B,  -Pi/2 + I Infinity, -Pi/2, Pi/2, Pi/2 - I Infinity}`, but not `{B, I Infinity, 0, Pi, -I Infinity}` - unless I'm being stupid of course.

Comment: `{B, I Infinity, 0, Pi, -I Infinity}` - that's... not the same path; you're now integrating over the imaginary axis.

Comment: @0x4A4D        Sorry - that was a typo - it should read `{B, I Infinity, 0, Pi, Pi -I Infinity}` - which is (from the linked diagram in the initial post) a permissible contour. Even if I shift a little i.e. `{B, -d + I Infinity, -d, Pi-d, Pi-d -I Infinity}` where `d` is small, I get different results. Thanks for all your help btw.

Comment: "...where `d` is small" - that'd be ill-conditioning at work; I'd avoid contours that hug the imaginary axis myself.

Comment: Ok. Thanks again. I'll revisit the derivation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(This is more of a plausibility argument than a rigorous answer.)

I had previously mentioned that one would want to avoid contours that go too near to the imaginary axis, since the resulting integrals will tend to be ill-conditioned. If my words were not sufficiently convincing, then maybe a few pictures might help you see what I'm seeing:

```
With[{m = 3, z = 1}, 
     Table[Plot3D[With[{β = u + I v}, f[Exp[I m β + I z Cos[β]]]],
                  {u, -π, π}, {v, -6, 6},
                  BoundaryStyle -> None, BoxRatios -> {1, 3/2, 3/2}, ClippingStyle -> None,
                  Mesh -> False, PlotLabel -> f, PlotRange -> {-10, 10},
                  PlotStyle -> Directive[Pink, Specularity[White, 50], Opacity[0.8]]],
           {f, {Re, Im}}] // GraphicsRow]
```

[image: integrand for Hankel function contour integral]

The pictures given above are plots of the real and imaginary parts of $\exp(i m \beta + i z \cos\beta)$ for $m=3$ and $z=1$, within the region $-\pi < \Re \beta < \pi$. As you might notice, the integrand varies rather wildly on the imaginary axis; it stands to reason that a contour that lies too near to it will give function values that vary wildly as well, making numerical computations of the contour integral unstable. You'll thus want a contour that tries to keep away from the "forest". In particular, contours that lie on $\Re \beta=-\pi/2$ for $\Im \beta > 0$ and $\Re \beta=\pi/2$ for $\Im \beta < 0$ are at a comfortable distance from the "forest", which makes them suitable for quadrature.

Answer (score 2):

This should really be a comment, but I don't have enough reputation to do that, so I post it as an answer instead.

I took a close look at your first integration path, they all lay within region where the integrand is actually well-behaved: smooth change and only one or two oscillations, there shouldn't be any significant error in your Hmz function. So I changed the $\infty$ of integration bound to some number large enough for the integrand to vanish. The result with $\infty$ replaced by $10$ is:

$$0.0195634 - 5.82152 i $$

So the error should be caused by Mathematica's way of handling infinite integration bound, not the integrand.